# ng-pattern allows space when regex should prohibit it

Tags: regex, angularjs

`ng-pattern` is allowing spaces with the following pattern and I cannot understand why it would do so.

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\d\-\_]+$/"
```

I have tried without escaping the `-` and `_`, and the result is the same: the classes `ng-valid` and `ng-valid-pattern` are applied.

I am trying to only allow a-z (both capital and lower case) and dash and underscore. The pattern seems to work as I'd expect on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nE2uZ5/2) so this is quite confusing.

UPDATE:
the text field is marked as invalid after a valid character is typed after a space, but not when the space is the first character:
eg (not really hardcoded like this, the "someText" and "some text" are typed into the text inputs):

```
<input> someText</input> //ng-valid
<input>some text</input> //ng-invalid
```

Still quite confused why this would be.

Comment: It is not the problem with the pattern: `^[a-zA-Z\d\-\_]+$` or `^[a-zA-Z\d_-]*$` do not allow spaces.

Comment: @stribizhev Yeah, right. So it is a problem with how I am using `ng-pattern`? But that seems very straightforward. I cannot see what I've done wrong.

Comment: Yes, `ng-trim`: [*If set to false Angular will not automatically trim the input. This parameter is ignored for input\[type=password\] controls, which will never trim the input.

(default: true)*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Angular trims inputs automatically. You can disable it by ng-trim="false"

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-trim="false" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\d\-\_]+$/"/>
```

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

Answer (score 4):

I think it is because the ng-pattern will trim your input first. So
`<input> someText</input> //` is actually the same as `<input>someText</input>`

Comment: You can use ng-trim="false" to disable this behavior