# Should not allow the space in password field?

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

Need to show error message whenever i enter space in password input field using ng-pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for not allowing spaces in the input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334765/regular-expression-for-not-allowing-spaces-in-the-input-field)

Comment: What have you tried? You just have to use an `ng-pattern` like `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\d\-\_]+$/"` and set `ng-trim="false"`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31417133/3153169)

Comment: Keep checking on change `pass.indexOf('_')` its easy to check and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of regEx - `/^\S*$/` does not allow space anywhere in the string.

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input type='password' name="passInpt" ng-model='pass' data-ng-pattern="/^\S*$/">
   <div data-ng-show="myForm.passInpt.$error.pattern" >White Space not allowed</div>
</form>
```

DEMO:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input type='password' name="passInpt" ng-model='pass' data-ng-pattern="/^\S*$/">
    <div data-ng-show="myForm.passInpt.$error.pattern">White Space not allowed</div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link [Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ccncwxn9/2/)

You can check for indexof or you can use regX for it.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">

    <form>
      <span>{{error}}</span>
      <input type='password' ng-model='pass' ng-change='check()'>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS **

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.error = '';
    $scope.check = function() {
      $scope.pass.indexOf(' ') > -1 ? ($scope.error = 'Invalid') : ($scope.error = '');
    }
  })
```

Hope this will help you

updated for space

Comment: Its not showing the error message if i enter space.